# Unity - FireBase Realtime DataBase ValueChanged Method not working after moving GameObject to another Scene

Tags: database, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

im working on a Game in Unity and want to Safes the User data in Firebase Realtime Database (Will just call it Firebase from now on).

I came up with the idea to create a GameObject, attach a Script (https://github.com/xBarkeeper/2DRun/blob/main/Assets/MainMenu/Scripts/MonoUser.cs) to it and load the Data in the Start scene. The Script had the ValueChanged Method from FireBase in it, so every time data in Firebase changed, it also get updated in the GameObject.

My Plan was to pass this GameObject through my entire Game, so i don't habe to matter about the Userdata anymore.

No I have two Problems with it:

1. When I move the Object from one Scene to another, the ValueChanged Method is not working anymore. (Not listening to the FireBase)
2. When I have a other GameObject that is using FireBase, it works completely fine until I use setDataBaseValues or ContinueWithOnMainThread. Both of them first runs when I stop my unity run. But then work successfully.

I don't really know what Code I should attach to this question.

For Example to Problem 2:

```
Debug.Log("Log 1");
       DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
       Debug.Log("Log 2");
       this.userName = userName;
       FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
       .GetReference(userName)
       .GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
       {
           if (task.IsFaulted)
           {
               Debug.Log("Log 3");
           }
           else if (task.IsCompleted)
           {
               DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
               Debug.Log("Log 4");
               this.uuid = snapshot.Child("uuid").GetValue(true).ToString();
               Debug.Log("Log 5");
           }
       });
```

Log 2 is called directly. Log 4 is printed when I end my Game.

Also tried have a Scene loaded through my entire Game with the GameObject attached. But in the moment I load a new Scene, it also don't listen to the ValuesChanged Method anymore.

Isn't it possible to send a FireBase Object between Scenes with a working ValuesChanged?

Do I really need to create a FireBase Object in each scene, although then the data must always be downloaded again?

And why the setDatabaseValues Thread starts first on stoping my Unity Game?

Answer (score 0):

For problem 1: is the gameObject marked as "DontDestroyOnLoad"?
When do you register the OnValueChanged () method?
Before doing anything, do you initialize Firebase Database?

For problem 2: use this code by substituting the line before Debug.Log ("Log 5”);

```
this.uuid = System.Convert.ToString(snapshot.Child("uuid").GetValue(true));
```

I usually use "Value" instead of "GetValue()", but it should be the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. The GameObject is Untagged. I initialise my Firebase Database and also register the ValueChanged Method in the Awake Method. See the Script:

https://github.com/xBarkeeper/2DRun/blob/main/Assets/MainMenu/Scripts/MonoUser.cs

"Log 5" is also called and i the data get the Data correct from the Database. But not until I press the game stop button in unity

Comment: Try using the code I wrote.
In your code you used ToString(), but for me it usually blocks the script. With the System.Convert.ToString(...) method this does not happend
If you put a Debug.Log("...") before the DataSnapshot snapshot = ... line, what happens?

Comment: I added the System.Convert.ToString and a Debug.Log("Log 3.5") before the DataSnapshot. It still wait until I press the stop button. Also the Log 3.5 is printed after stop button

Comment: Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
                if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
                {
                    Database = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;
                }
                else
                {
                     //error...
                }
            });

Comment: Try to use that code to initialize firebase database

Comment: Try replacing ContinueWith Main Thread with ContinueWith.
If it still doesn't work try to create a project from scratch where you import only Firebase Database and try to change some values ​​in the database.